# How to execute dictionary keys/values as commands in shell?

Tags: python, linux

How would I execute python dictionary key/values as commands in a linux kernel? For example:

```
keys = {
        "echo" : "hello",
        "touch" : "nothing"
       }
```

and I wanted to run the first key/value pair to run in the shell "echo hello".

I've tried using the `json` module, but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys. Given the structure you would need one key and a list: `keys = {"echo":["hello","nothing"]}`

Answer (score 0):

In python, the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module can be used to handle system calls. It would perhaps easier to define the commands in a list

```
import subprocess
commands = [['echo', 'foo'], ['echo', 'bar']]
for c in commands:
    subprocess.run(c)
```

If you wish to use a dictionary instead, it can of course be done (this is for Python 3):

```
commands = {'echo': 'hello'}
for c in commands.items():
    print(c)
```

But here, each command (for example `echo`) can only appear once as mentioned in the comments.